# Trying to get the command window to not go away

Tags: c#

I am very new to C#. So please help me with this doubt.

When I run this code, the screen will pause and wait for an input.

```
    namespace HelloWorld1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //int x=2;
                Console.WriteLine("Hello world! Enter an int.");
                Console.Read();
               /* x=Console.Read();
                Console.WriteLine("you've entered: " + x + " .");
                Console.ReadLine();
                */
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I change the code to below, it the screen no longer pause... :

```
namespace HelloWorld1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x=2;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world! Enter an int.");
            //Console.Read();
            x=Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("you've entered: " + x + " .");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Edit:

latest code (still doesn't pause screen):

```
namespace HelloWorld1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x=2;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world! Enter an int.");
            x=Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("you've entered: " + x + " .");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It displays both lines of text and the window closes... I need for it to pause so I can actually see the output and learn by making changes...

Comment: Latest code: replace first Read() with ReadLine().

Comment: @glexey then i get an error, can not convert string to int.

Comment: That's right, you have to convert your string input to int if you want to assign it to integer variable, e.g.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx. The reason Read() didn't error out is because it returned an ascii code (which is integer) of the first character you entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your Console Application with 'Start without Debugging' Mode `(Ctrl+F5)` from the Debug menu.

> If you run a Console application with plain old F5, the console window flashes on the screen and disappears, unless you add a Console.ReadLine to your code; with Control_F5, the console window is held on the screen until you hit the Return key.

*Source: [Visual Studio Tip: The Difference Between Start Without Debugging and Start with Debugging](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2013/10/start-without--debugging-and-start-with-debugging.aspx)*

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/01/start-debugging-vs-start-without-debugging-vstipdebug0037.aspx

Comment: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2013/10/start-without--debugging-and-start-with-debugging.aspx

Answer (score 5):

What's the purpose of using the Read() method? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "returns the next character from the input stream, or negative one (-1) if there are currently no more characters to be read. ... Subsequent calls to the Read method retrieve your input one character at a time. After the final character is retrieved, Read blocks its return again and the cycle repeats."

Use Readline() instead.

Comment: I tried ReadLine(), it also does the same. the window will go away after displaying the two lines of output.

Comment: @psj01 `Console.ReadLine()` is the main way to keep the window open. The window will only close once you press enter.

Comment: Then I suggest updating your question with the exact ReadLine code you've tried. I suspect you first did Read(), then ReadLine(). You need two of ReadLine(), first to wait for number input, second to wait for "permission to close the window".

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Read()` basically reads a character so if you are on a console and you press a key the console will close, meanwhile `Console.Readline()` will read the whole string and returns the next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more lines are available. In the first part of the code,  the console waits for a key to be pressed, that's why the windows hangs around. To achieve your objective, I suggest `Console.ReadKey()` method, which obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user. The pressed key is displayed in the console window as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: but the reason why I added the Console.ReadLine() at the end was to get the window to pause so it won't close automatically.  But no matter what I use ( Console.ReadLine() or  Console.Read() ) , it closes the window right after it displays : "you've entered: " + x + " ." , line.

Comment: Ofcourse it does, in the first part of the code, the console waits for a key to be pressed, that's why the windows hangs around.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `Read` function, it only returns the next character, which leaves the newline (from when you press enter) in the buffer. Then when you call `ReadLine`, it automatically reads the newline left, and then the application closes. Use `ReadLine` to get your int, and convert it:

```
int x = 2;
Console.WriteLine("Hello world! Enter an int.");

x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Change this line right here

Console.WriteLine("you've entered: " + x + " .");
Console.ReadLine();
```